# How to make plotting with "jfreecharts" more dynamic?

Tags: java, dynamic, jfreechart

**Introduction**

My goal is to input a set of products and choose an option for display such as:

```
System.out.print("Input number of products to represent: ");
      prodNum = scan.nextInt();
      String[] prodName = new String[prodNum];
System.out.print("Enter which products to represent: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < prodName.length; i++)
         {
           prodName[i] = scan.next();
         }
System.out.println("----Options----");
System.out.println("1. Cantidad");
System.out.println("2. Calidad");
System.out.println("3. RealmQ");
System.out.println("4. Coste");
      option = scan.nextInt();                

      userOptionWas(option);
```

then by using JFreeCharts I wanted to be able to choose how many lines (for each product I input) and what option to display (quantity, quality and stuff) which is stored inside some obviously named arrays.

**My approach**

```
  private XYDataset multipleLine(int prodNum, String[] prodName, int option){

   XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

   XYSeries product3 = new XYSeries("product3");
   XYSeries product4 = new XYSeries("product4");
   XYSeries product5 = new XYSeries("product5");
   XYSeries product6 = new XYSeries("product6");
   XYSeries product7 = new XYSeries("product7");
   XYSeries product8 = new XYSeries("product8");

   switch(prodNum)
   {
       case(2):
       {

           if (option == 1)
           {
                XYSeries product1 = new XYSeries(prodName[0]);
                XYSeries product2 = new XYSeries(prodName[1]);

                for (int i = 0; i < CSVinput.cantidad.length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (CSVinput.nombre[i].equals(prodName[0]))
                        {                            
                            product1.add(i, CSVinput.cantidad[i]);
                        }
                    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
                    }
           }
           if (option == 2)
           {

           }
           if (option == 3)
           {

           }
           if (option == 4)
           {

           }

       }
   }       
   return dataset;
 }
```

Halfway through implementing my idea I started to wonder if it is not possible to do it, or just I am in the wrong path to my goal.

**What I expect**

- I want to be able to create different plots from a simple menu I showed before.
- If it is possible, dynamic (**if I input 2 products the program displays 2 lines referring to each product**)

**Extra Notes**

- I am new at JFreeCharts.
- Take a moment here at `product1.add(i, CSVinput.cantidad[i]);` where I use (int)"i" instead of my (String)"date" format. Why I am not able to use a String? Is there any way to bypass this?

**What I expect from this question**

I would like to know more efficient and friendly ways to achieve this without too much unnecessary complexity.

**Data Example**

```
2018/12/29-Tejido,321 908,13.55,43.18,$15.98,
2018/12/29-Ropa,195 045,20.55,45.93,$123.01,
2018/12/29-Gorra de visera,126 561,17.43,42.32,$79.54,
2018/12/29-Cerveza,80 109,3.37,17.93,$12.38,
2018/12/29-Mercancías de playa,75 065,11.48,39.73,$105.93,
2018/12/29-Bebidas alcohólicas,31 215,4.84,27.90,$32.29,
2018/12/29-Artículos de cuero,19 098,23.13,44.09,$198.74,
2018/12/29-Bolsas y carteras,7 754,23.09,41.34,$1 176.54,
2018/12/30-Tejido,252 229,12.86,43.14,$18.87,
2018/12/30-Ropa,132 392,18.09,46.02,$177.58,
2018/12/30-Gorra de visera,87 676,14.42,42.46,$122.48,
2018/12/30-Cerveza,44 593,2.72,17.79,$18.71,
2018/12/30-Mercancías de playa,44 593,8.26,39.56,$200.78,
2018/12/30-Bebidas alcohólicas,27 306,4.30,23.88,$31.95,
2018/12/30-Artículos de cuero,16 147,21.08,43.91,$207.49,
2018/12/30-Bolsas y carteras,6 552,21.11,40.59,$1 195.41,
2019/01/02-Tejido,321 908,13.55,43.18,$15.98,
2019/01/02-Ropa,195 045,20.55,45.93,$123.01,
2019/01/02-Gorra de visera,126 561,17.43,42.32,$79.54,
2019/01/02-Cerveza,80 109,3.37,17.93,$12.38,
2019/01/02-Mercancías de playa,75 065,11.48,39.73,$105.93,
2019/01/02-Bebidas alcohólicas,31 215,4.84,27.90,$32.29,
2019/01/02-Artículos de cuero,19 098,23.13,44.09,$198.74,
2019/01/02-Bolsas y carteras,7 754,23.09,41.34,$1 176.54,
2019/01/03-Tejido,1 164 607,12.87,43.14,$15.54,
2019/01/03-Ropa,131 409,17.18,45.97,$161.17,
2019/01/03-Gorra de visera,79 242,13.54,43.17,$100.38,
2019/01/03-Cerveza,48 332,2.80,18.10,$17.48,
2019/01/03-Mercancías de playa,46 157,8.70,38.39,$180.54,
2019/01/03-Bebidas alcohólicas,25 210,4.04,23.72,$33.52,
2019/01/03-Artículos de cuero,14 321,19.56,39.92,$216.00,
2019/01/03-Bolsas y carteras,5 814,19.85,39.68,$1 227.29,
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot for the help I think I have learnt but the way is never ending as by some reason, the instance which takes the dataset does not plot the dataset
**What I am missing?**.

PD: **Let me know in the comments if you need CSVinput in order to provide a solution.**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.SeriesException;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

import webscrapper.CSVinput;

/**
 *
 * @author Jonathan
 */
public class TimeSeriesChartExample extends ApplicationFrame{

    //To parse dates below and be able to debug outside the loop
    public static String[] dateSplit;

    //Instace that declares properties and uses the dataset to create the chart
    public TimeSeriesChartExample(String title) 
    {
       super(title);
       // Create dataset
       XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
       // Create chart
       JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
           "Titulo", // Chart
           "Date", // X-Axis Label
           "Number", // Y-Axis Label
           dataset);

        //Changes background color
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255,228,196));  
    }
    //Create the set of data to be plotted
    private XYDataset createDataset() 
    {
        //A collection of datasets
        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        //The object were this new series are added thus it's name
        TimeSeries prod1 = new TimeSeries("Cantidad");

            //"For each" name stored in the array
            for (int i = 0; i < CSVinput.nombre.length; i++)
            {
                //If name equals 
                if ("Ropa".equals(CSVinput.nombre[i]))
                {
                    //Pass the "i" position to work it
                    dateSplit = CSVinput.fecha[i].split("/");
                        //Parse the date
                        int day = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
                        int year = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
                        System.out.println("day is: " + day);
                    //Pass the parsed date and the value from CSV.cantidad at "i" position referring to the name "Ropa"
                    prod1.add(new Day(day, month, year), CSVinput.cantidad[i]);
                    System.out.println(CSVinput.cantidad[i]);//Debug stuff
                }         
            }                    
            //Add everything to the dataset
            dataset.addSeries(prod1);     
        //Return it
        return dataset;
    }
    private XYDataset createDataset2()
    {
        //A collection of datasets
        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        //The object were this new series are added thus it's name
        TimeSeries prod2 = new TimeSeries("Cantidad");

            //"For each" name stored in the array
            for (int i = 0; i < CSVinput.nombre.length; i++)
            {
                //If name equals 
                if (CSVinput.nombre[i] == "Tejido")
                {
                    //Pass the "i" position to work it
                    dateSplit = CSVinput.fecha[i].split("/");
                        //Parse the date
                        int day = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
                        int year = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);
                    //Pass the parsed date and the value from CSV.cantidad at "i" position referring to the name "Ropa"
                    prod2.add(new Day(day, month, year), CSVinput.cantidad[i]);
                    System.out.println(CSVinput.cantidad[i]);//Debug stuff
                }         
            }                    
            //Add everything to the dataset
            dataset.addSeries(prod2);     
        //Return it
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {       
       //Custom class to import data from the csv into arrays (TODO: make it dynamic)
       CSVinput.ImportData("caca.csv");

       /* //More debugg stuff
       dateSplit = CSVinput.fecha[1].split("/");
       System.out.println("year: " + dateSplit[0] + " month: " + dateSplit[1] + " day: " + dateSplit[2]);
       */

       //Create an instance of the previous class 
       final TimeSeriesChartExample example = new TimeSeriesChartExample("ItWorks!");
       example.pack(); //Part from the ApplicationFrame
       RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(example); //Render the graph at the center of screen
       example.setVisible(true);  //make it visible
    }
    }
```

Comment: As you see the comments are made so I understand some of it from the docs and other helpful posts in this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, focus on you program's data model:

- If your series include a time domain, consider using a `TimeSeriesCollection` of `TimeSeries` rather than `XYSeries`; `TimeSeriesChartDemo1`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603723/230513), is a basic example; parse dates as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173688/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37975536/230513); for database access, consider a `JDBCXYDataset`.
- As you read the data for each series, store the series in a `List<TimeSeries>`, rather than an array; if latency is a problem, do the parsing in the background, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

The exact details will depend on your application's design, but using the [observer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) will minimize complexity; the basic principle is to update the *model* (`Dataset`) and the listening *view* (`JFreeChart`) will update itself in response. Using Swing for example, you can control the displayed chart in several ways:

- Use your `List<TimeSeries>` to construct a suitable `ListModel<TimeSeries>`; for the series menu, make your chosen model a `DefaultComboBoxModel<TimeSeries>` for a `JComboBox` or a `DefaultListModel<TimeSeries>` for a `JList`.
- Add a suitable listener to your menu component; give your `XYPlot` a `TimeSeriesCollection`; use `addSeries()` or `removeSeries()` to alter the plot as a series is selected; alternatively, use `setSeriesVisible()` to toggle visibility, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286042/230513).

For a command-line interface, the interactions are less complex but also less versatile:

- Use a `List<TimeSeries>` to build your `TimeSeriesCollection`.
- Use the `TimeSeriesCollection` methods to control what the listening `XYPlot` displays.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I will try to implement this today. Also, check the link at `observer pattern` it can't be reached.

Comment: Could you provide me an example with the list of timeSeries? I understood most of it but still can't see how I could manage to create a graph with the data I want to. So far, I thought about create everything and make visible only the options chosen on the menu but doesn't it look like a bit brute?

Comment: @WhiteGlove: Updated links to pattern and example; the basic principle is to update the _model_ and the listening _view_ will update itself in response; brute force reading reduces _perceived_ latency; memory is cheap, soabstract early and limit cache only if necessary.

Comment: I made use of some of your ideas. Thanks a lot, right now I'm working at a bug(minor) I can't solve. Maybe I will post it later.

Comment: Excellent; ping me with a link if the need arises; sorry, previously overlooked your update; I'm unfamiliar with `CSVinput`, but I usually use one of the date parsing methods cited above.